# Is it true that the eigenvalues of $A + B$ are the sum of some eigenvalue of $A$ and some eigenvalue of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it true that the eigenvalues of $A + B$ are the sum of some eigenvalue of $A$ and some eigenvalue of $B$?

I'm taking a linear algebra class, and I recently learned about eigenvalues. I think that this claim is true, but it is not a theorem that I can find anywhere. I've tried it for many examples, and I just wanted someone to confirm.

Thanks

Comment: $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector $x$ (corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ respectively, say), _then_ we have $$(A + B)x = Ax + Bx = \lambda_A x + \lambda_B x = (\lambda_A + \lambda_B)x$$ which shows that $\lambda_A + \lambda_B$ is an eigenvalue of $A + B$ (with the very same eigenvector). Otherwise, this does not hold in general (although it may happen merely by chance that _some_ eigenvalue of $A + B$ happens to be a sum of some eigenvalue of $A$ and some eigenvalue of $B$, for no discernible reason).

Comment: As a special case of this, since every vector is an eigenvector of $I$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, we see that the eigenvalues of $A + I$ are exactly $\lambda_i + 1$, for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$. More generally $\lambda_i + kI$ are the eigenvalues of $A + kI$, for any constant $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are zero while $B$ are $\pm i$ and the eigenvalues of their sum matrix are $\pm i\sqrt{2}$. But $$0 \pm i \neq \pm i\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: @M.Vinay: I edit my answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Ah, nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

Take

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},~B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are given by $\lambda_{1/2}=1$ and $\lambda'_{1/2}=\pm1$. The sum is of those is

$$C=A+B=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The corresponding eigenvalues are $\mu_{1/2}=1\pm\sqrt 2$ which cannot be interpreted as sum of the aforementioned eigenvalues.

---

I think the reason why you were not able to find this conjectured theorem within the literature is that it fails in general. As shown by finding a single counterexample we have to admit that it does not hold for all matrices, but it may be true for certain ones.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already shown by providing counterexamples, the result you mentioned doesn't generally hold. Yet, if $A$ and $B$ commute then it is true.

Comment: Proof for commuting matrices following this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to find a counterexample.

The Eigenvalues of

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$$ and \begin{pmatrix}3&0\\1&4\end{pmatrix} are found on the diagonals and are integer.

The Eigenvalues of

$$\begin{pmatrix}4&1\\1&6\end{pmatrix}$$

are the roots of $(4-\lambda)(6-\lambda)-1$, which are irrational (the discriminant is not a perfect square).